# How to calculate difference between two rows

Tags: mysql, influxdb

I have a db table called serverstatus that stores time and status as below. At any given time how should i find the total downtime?

```
Time Status
10:00 UP
11:30 DOWN
12:00 UP
14:00 DOWN
15:00 UP
```

Fo example at 16:00 the total downtime is 1 hr 30 minutes. I tried to do a self join and substract between two consecutive rows but couldn't get correct answer

```
Select A.time-min(B.time) from serverstatus A, serverstatus B where A.status="UP" and B.status="DOWN" and B.time < A.time
```

Comment: Do you have to do this only using mysql ?

Comment: Yes i need to use mysql to get the downtime at given point of time

Comment: Better try with a function/procedure

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with row number simulation if row_number function is not available to you in your mysql version

```
select  #s.*,t.*,timediff(endtime,starttime) duration
            sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(timediff(endtime,starttime))) / 60) Downduration
from
(
select  t.time starttime,t.status,@rn:=@rn+1 rn,
            @p:=status p
from t,(select @rn:=0,@p:='') r
order by time
) s
join
(
select  t.time endtime,t.status,@rn1:=@rn1+1 rn1,
            @p1:=status p1
from t,(select @rn1:=0,@p1:='') r1
order by time
) t on t.rn1 = s.rn + 1
where s.status = 'Down' and t.status = 'Up'

+---------------+
| Downduration  |
+---------------+
| 00:01:30.0000 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```